# How to access an API with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I want to be able to navigate outside my Angular 2 app to *mywebsite.com/api*. **This should take me to an API app hosted in the same server.**

This is my current route setup.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

How would I exclude the path since I don't need a component or a template for it?

Comment: Are you saying you want to hit an api endpoint? You would need to do this with the http package for angular2. What is the back end your using?

Comment: I am hosting a php app that receives and replies json.

Comment: So what you are trying to do is hit the api end point then handle the response right?

Comment: yea that's correct

Answer (score 0):

In `angular2` you will make `api` call using the [http docs here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html),

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor( private router: Router, private auth: Auth, private http: Http  ) { }

  private personalSubmit() { 
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return this.http
      .post('http://localhost:4200/api/apiEndpointURL', 
        this.personal, 
        { headers: headers })
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe((res)=>{
            //do something with the response here
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
```

This is an example of posting a form. The values in the form are `post` and the response is `console.log` to the `terminal` in this case. This is an example working with the node.js back end. I am not sure what would need to be changed for `php` but in the end you will need the `http package`. The only thing is you might need to change the application type depending on what you are returning.

I believe for `php` you use this as the application type,

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
```

I found ane xample for php using

Comment: Thanks, I will be communicating with the api in the future but I also want to be able to host the php api so that a mobile app can communicate with it. It seems I have to leave a route open but the angular docs are not clear on that.

Comment: In node you create the route for the back end so there is an end point that exist. But if you are using angular2 as a separate application as far as I know the http method will make the call. The api end point will have to exist on the api side so it fires off when you hit it with the post you make. I can show you how it is created in node / express. Most importantly. Make sure you read about http so you understand how to form the function with your data. http is actually really easy to use. But ya your going to have to create some end points on the php side.

Comment: would the above code work if the api are in the same server? 

Basically, on the web app when you hit htttp://mywebsite/**api** it would go the php files (api endpoint)

Comment: As far as for making the request you are making an http request. That being said there are things that could come into play that might block a request like that depending on the configuration of the server

Comment: @mcfresh here is an angular 2 question with someone who is posting from angular2 to larval back end. I think this also might help you write the query on the angular2 side http://stackoverflow.com/q/40934415/2218253 I understand your not using the larval back end but I assume it could help cause it is still making a call to a php back end.