# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: issue on sending headers in Angular2 post request to laravel

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, http-headers, cross-domain

I am using angular2+laravel and I am trying to post the request with *headers* but its giving *Cross-Origin Request Blocked:* error. If any body knows how to resolve it.

I did some possible solution like enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in htaccess file of laravel and created CORS Middleware but these solutions are not working. Here is my code of angular.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import configApp = require('../_configs/app.settings');
//import '../assets/frontend/custom/js/jquery.toaster.config.js';
declare function maketoast(status: string, message: string) : void;


@Injectable()
export class ForgotpasswordService {

constructor(private http: Http) { }

forgotPassword(email: string, token: string) {

    alert(token)
    var headers = new Headers();

   // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application11/json');

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token;
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    // console.log(configApp.apiUrl+/test);
    return this.http.post(configApp.apiUrl+"/password/email", JSON.stringify({ email: email, apiRequest:1}), options } )
        .map((response: Response) => {

            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let user = response.json();

            console.log(user.status);
            if(user.status == false){

                maketoast(user.toaster_status, user.message);
                event.stopImmediatePropagation;
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();

            }


            if (user.status == true) {

                maketoast(user.toaster_status, user.message);

            }
        });

}

resetPassword(token: string, email: string, password: string,     confirmPassword: string) {


    // console.log(configApp.apiUrl+/test);
    return this.http.post(configApp.apiUrl+"/password/reset",   JSON.stringify({ token: token, email: email, password: confirmPassword, confirmPassword: password, apiRequest:1}))
        .map((response: Response) => {

            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            let user = response.json();

            console.log(user.status);
            if(user.status == false){

                maketoast(user.toaster_status, user.message);
                event.stopImmediatePropagation;
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();

            }


            if (user.status == true) {

                maketoast(user.toaster_status, user.message);

            }
        });

}
```

}

Comment: It's not an angular problem, but one with the api.  The CORS requirements must be set on the server.

Comment: Yes I have changed the .htaccess file and created a middleware for the same but not working at all.

Comment: What, precisely, does the error message say? Where is the server side code that you've written to set the CORS headers? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same problem but is not a server side problem, I installed barryvdh/laravel-cors and the headers are correct, but I still get `preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested`  but that header is on the response.

Answer (score 0):

This is server side  problem.

Create a middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

And add to your route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
```

//YOUR route code
    });

Answer (score 0):

I'm using laravel and angular 2.

On Laravel I installed the module barryvdh/laravel-cors and when I made a POST call the headers includes Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*".

But angular2 makes a preflight call using OPTIONS before POST, and Laravel wasn't sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" when the action was OPTION.

so, I add this to .htacess file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-   Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
```